# Xamarin.Forms physical key press event handling

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, keypress, custom-renderer

I'm developing Xamarin Forms app and I need to handle an event when physical button is pressed (on Android). What I've found out is that I can use DispatchKeyEvent inside an activity in Xamarin.Android project. However I don't know specifically how to do it.

In the shared code I have defined a ContentPage and I'm trying to override the DispatchKeyEvent inside a custom page renderer in Xamarin.Android. However, I get an error about missing constructor (I suppose it is related to layout, which is defined in the shared code, but I don't know why Xamarin.Android renderer doesn't use it).

How to solve this problem? Maybe there is some easier way to get info about key being pressed?

Comment: Could you please share the full log of this error when you tried to override the DispatchKeyEvent inside a custom page renderer in Xamarin.Android ?

Answer (score 0):

In the code behind for your page, you can override OnBackButtonPressed.

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
     return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
}
```